# Fixed point arithmetic with np.einsum

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to simulate fixed point arithmetic with `np.einsum`. For example, let's consider the following snippet that performs matrix multiplication:

```
A = np.random.uniform(size=(4, 5))
B = np.random.uniform(size=(5, 6))
C = np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A, B)
```

We can compute the aforementioned example using fixed-point arithmetic as follows:

```
num_bits = 16
s = 2**num_bits

tmp = A.reshape((4, 5, 1)) * B.reshape((1, 5, 6))
tmp = np.round(tmp * s).astype(np.int32)
C = np.sum(tmp, axis=1) / s
```

The drawback of the aforementioned code is that the intermediate tensor `tmp` can be pretty huge since we're doing the outer product first and performing reduction after. Is there a more efficient way to implement it using numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fxpmath](https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath) module. It has compatibility with Numpy's functions.

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

# Your matrices
A = np.random.uniform(size=(4, 5))
B = np.random.uniform(size=(5, 6))

# Fixed point conversion (define arbitrary `Qm.n` data type)
A_fxp = Fxp(A, dtype='Q16.16')
B_fxp = Fxp(B, dtype='Q16.16')

# Fixed point calculation
C_fxp = np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A_fxp, B_fxp)
```